# Issue importing assets created in blender into Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

Basically, I am created a VR game and I must create assets of buildings from around campus. I have never done this before so I am very new/not very knowledgeable with unity/blender.

Whenever I import my asset into unity (whether it be drag and drop into the assets folder inside of unity or me exporting it as a .fbx and importing in unity), I lose about half of my building.

[This is what my asset looks like in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uslRg.png)

[This is what my asset looks inside of blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO2Bg.png)

Any help would be appreciated... I'm sure I have left out a lot of needed information. I can also provide the files if needed...

Thank you.

Edit: It also has no materials attached so that can't be an issue

Edit 2: Well, apparently my entire model is non-manifold. Time to restart. Again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the normals of the building are facing the wrong the direction. Just recalculate the normals of the building (inside edit mode - space - "recalculate normals")

Edit: dont forget to select all faces before recalculating the normals