# Why does My (FBX) Mesh have holes when exported from blender to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, fbx

I'm learning to sculpt my characters now and when I export the FBX file from Blender to Unity the Mesh has a giant hole in the face. How can I prevent/Fix this? It works just fine in mixamo.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3yhO.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSTOq.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MSq8.jpg)

Comment: What happens if you just import the Blender file into Unity directly?  Skip FBX export.  Just in case.

Comment: In Blender enable Backface Culling and see if the whole is there as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue importing assets created in blender into Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55202251/issue-importing-assets-created-in-blender-into-unity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your faces have inverted normals. Unity interprets them as backfaces and the default material shaders cull them (don't render them).

The solution is very simple. Select all your models verticies in blender edit mode press `alt+n` and select `recalculate outside`. After that you should be able to export it and display everything correctly in Unity.

Comment: thank you soooooo much, it worked .You saved me a whole day? weeks? of research. You are the real hero in this story!!!!